# Github + Deploy Keys...

Tags: git, github

I have deploy keys set up on my server that I use to pull from github. My question is, What branch gets pulled when I pull using deploy keys? If I do a `git status` I see 
`# On branch deploy
nothing to commit (working directory clean)`

What is `branch deploy`? the Master? the Default? Can I pick?

Comment: Well... you are all right. I guess at some point, there was a deploy branch created. Its not in github, just locally on that server.I even went as far as to create an example project and set up deploy keys. This question should be erased from StackOverFlow and hopefully from my memories :) Thanks everyone!

Comment: please just accept one of the answers. Three people put effort into this, so deleting the question would be a waste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branch `deploy` is exactly that: the branch called `deploy`. You can switch the branch by going into the repo directory and doing a `git checkout <name-of-branch>`, e.g. `git checkout master`.

Comment: Where does it come from? What if my I want to deploy a different branch?

Comment: If `deploy` exists on your server but not on GitHub, you might have accidentally done a `git checkout -b deploy` or `git branch deploy` or some such command. Or, you might have had a `deploy` branch at some point in the past and deleted it from GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Branch `deploy` is the *name* of the branch you're on. I.e. not `master`, rather `deploy`.

If you wish to switch *back* to your master branch:

```
git checkout master
```

Now when you *pull* from Github, you're pulling into your current branch. In your case `deploy`.

Comment: Apparently, you do, at least on that server.

Comment: @a.m. Yes, you most likely do. Run the command: `git branch` and you should  see all your branches listed.

Answer (score 1):

Do a

```
git branch
```

for clarity; it will show you that you are on a branch named deploy (indicated with an asterisk)

Then do

```
gitk
```

to show where the deploy branch is in your tree